# Compatible version of "Adobe Shockwave Player?"

Tags: firefox

Is there a Ubuntu compatible version of the "Adobe Shockwave Player?" I'm running Firefox and when I try to bring up one of my School's websites it says missing plugin. When I click on "Install missing plug-in" it says none found, so when I click on manually install plug-in it takes me to Adobe Shockwave Player installation, but there is no ubuntu version to install??? On the Firefox plug-in finder service it says "Unknown Plugin (application/x-director)

Comment: Question is now obsolete as Shockwave has been discontinued altogether since April 2019.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Shockwave player is only available for Windows. You can use mozplugger(a program that lets you "embed" other programs in your web browser.) along with wine and windows version of firefox

- First, install the wine and mozplugger packages (from the software center).
- Now download and install the Windows version of Firefox . Download it from [Mozilla's web site](http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-4.0.1&os=win&lang=en-US). Now double click it and install it .
- Run the windows version of firefox .
- Now go to a web site [that requires Shockwave](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/), and choose to get the missing plugin. Again, follow the on-screen instructions, and when the plugin has installed and is working, you may close Firefox.
- Now you need to configure mozplugger to use the Windows version of Firefox for Shockwave files. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

  `gksudo gedit`

then open the /etc/mozpluggerrc file

Add the following two lines to the end of the file:

```
application/x-director: dir,dcr,dxr,cst,cct,cxt,w3d,fgd,swa: Macromedia Director file
        swallow(firefox.exe) fill stream: wine "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" -chrome "$file"
```

Now open a Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and paste

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/pluginreg.dat
```

Now run the native version of firefox and test the shockwave player by visting [this site](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/) .

[Modified From Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Shockwave)

Comment: too much long process. isn't there any easy way?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to use this along with https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/339841/222105 to try to get Shockwave running on Ubuntu 18.04.  We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave#Platform_support):

> Unlike Flash, the Shockwave browser plugin is not available for Linux or Solaris despite intense lobbying efforts.  However, the Shockwave Player can be installed on Linux with [CrossOver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossOver) or by running a Windows version of a supported browser in [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) (with varying degrees of success).

Try running it with [CrossOver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossOver) or [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

Comment: I "sadly" accept this answer, but to be honest "Wine" sucks and "Crossover" is a paid app!

Comment: CrossOver is based on Wine, and Wine works better. So no hard feelings there.

Comment: I suggest to your school, to use cross-platform and popular method. JS and Flash is enough... I think.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there's no Shockwave for Linux. I suggest installing Firefox and Shockwave in *WINE*, that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Just finished "trying" to get Wine to work on my system...no luck!

Answer (score 3):

Install PlayOnLinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Install the windows version of firefox.

When the installation finishes, PlayOnLinux will ask if you wish to install additional plugins to firefox, select the shockwave plugin.

If you receive a "Error - bad format" when trying to load a shockwave application, you will need to go to the [Adobe Shockwave Test Page](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/), right click anywhere over the image that displays the shockwave version and select "Properties...", then uncheck "Allow backwards compatibility".

Answer (score 0):

Shockwave has been dead for quite a few years now. The thing you're looking for is Adobe Flash Player (I presume) which can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center.

You can search for Adobe Flash Player and it should pop up. Press 'Install' and you're on your way.

Comment: -1. The poster is clearly asking about Shockwave, not Flash.

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively, use Chromium web browser - this works for sites which fail in Firefox.

Comment: I don't think this will help, since AFAIK Chromium/Chrome do not come with a Shockwave plugin.