# How Do I Install Adobe Shockwave Player On Ubuntu?

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu compatible version of “Adobe Shockwave Player?”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48140/ubuntu-compatible-version-of-adobe-shockwave-player)

Could You Do It In Simple Steps? How Do You Use Mozilla plug-in to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48140/ubuntu-compatible-version-of-adobe-shockwave-player