# How to play shockwave flash?

Tags: firefox, totem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compatible version of “Adobe Shockwave Player?”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48140/compatible-version-of-adobe-shockwave-player)

Is there any workaround for Adobe Shockwave flash, I mean a plugin for Firefox, Totem or something like that. Is there any clone of Shockwave flash in Ubuntu.

I found that in the official Adobe site that Shockwave flash is not supported for Linux platforms.

While browsing the questions in this site I found this topic:

[Compatible version of "Adobe Shockwave Player?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48140/ubuntu-compatible-version-of-adobe-shockwave-player)

***KIND REQUEST:***

Please don't merge the topic with the one mentioned above. I'm asking you people about playing .swf ***WITHOUT USING WINE OR ANY OTHER MICROSOFT WINDOWS COMPATIBILITY LAYER SOFTWARES***

But is there any way to play .swf without using softwares that run due to compatibility programs like WINE, PlayOnLinux etc.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2.