# Flash won't work with ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Tags: flash

I've spent almost an entire day trying to make flash work. I first tried doing installing `adobe-flashplugin`. Firefox detects the plugin in `about:plugins`, but does not show the version number [ it is left blank ].

I tried removing `adobe-flashplugin` and installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. But the same result.

This is my output for `dpkg -l \*flash\*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-  ====================================================================
un  flashplayer-mozilla             <none>                                    (no description available)
un  flashplugin                     <none>                                    (no description available)
un  flashplugin-downloader          <none>                                    (no description available)
ii  flashplugin-installer           11.2.202.261ubuntu0. amd64                Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
un  flashplugin-nonfree             <none>                                    (no description available)
un  libflashsupport                 <none>                                    (no description available)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have in `~/.mozilla/plugins`? Do you see `libflashplayer.so` there?

Comment: Not initially. But then I uninstalled everything I had and got the tarball from adobe's site and then manually added it in `~/.mozilla/plugins/`. Still no luck

Comment: Just clarifying, firefox is detecting the plugin [ it shows up in `about:plugins` ]. But when I try [adobe's flash test](http://adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/) It shows `a plugin is needed to display this content` under `Adobe shockwave player`

Comment: the issue is that you have to install Shockwave Player, which doesn't exist for linux. There is workaround described here --> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Shockwave

Comment: If you just want a workaround, you can download and install Google Chrome: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Comment: @desgua Google Chrome does not have the plugin for Shockwave available.

Comment: @user125991 You would have to go to the test plage for Flash and not for Shockwave: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

Answer (score 1):

The Shockwave player is only available for Windows.

The solution is to install Shockwave in firefox in wine, and then call that one from Your linux firefox with mozplugger.

Here's a [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/48188/21679). It have several steps. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to debug this.

What you have installed, is not necessarily what you're actually running. It is typical to have old versions of flash installed in various places under `~/.mozilla/plugins` for example.

In order to figure out what's actually loaded into your browser, I suggest the following 3 step method:

- Figure out the process id of the process which loads the flash plugin this will depend on the browser, e.g. in firefox, you need to look for a process called `plugin-container`
- Run `lsof -p <pid> | grep libflashplayer` (replace `<pid>` by your step 1 discovered process id), to see the full path from which `libflashplayer.so` is actually loaded.
- Finally, once you have the full pathname of the `libflashplayer` DSO you can figure out its version by running `strings` on it and extracting what looks like a version number (4 numbers separated by dots)

Here's a little proof-of-concept shell script implementing `which-flash` on a running firefox.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# which flashplayer are we using?
#
# look for firefox-bin and/or plugin-container
#
pat="/([f]irefox-b|[p]lugin-co)"

for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        moz*)   pat="/[m]ozilla" ;;
        -x)     set -x ;;
    esac
done

# filter out parent procs (run-mozilla.sh) and grab the pids
pids=`ps xawww | egrep "$pat" | grep -v run-mozilla.sh | sed 's,^ *,,' | cut -d' ' -f 1`

for pid in $pids; do
    echo ======= pid: $pid =======
    output=`lsof -p $pid | grep libflashplayer`
    case "$output" in
        '')  echo "You need to load flash in the browser first" 1>&2;
            exit 1 ;;
    esac
    echo "$output"
    # extract the dso from the matching line:
    dso=`echo $output| awk '{print $NF}'`
    echo "flashplayer is in: $dso"
    # Also print version of libflashplayer:
    # Unfortunately there are many numbers in this dso, so we have
    # to restrict the major version number...
    echo version: `strings $dso | grep -P '^(1[1-9])\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\$'`
done
```

Chrome is similar except in the 1st step you need to look for the process that has a runtime argument like: `--plugin-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` in the ps output.  YMMV.

The reason to go through all this process is to ensure you're actually running what you think you are (the official installed version from `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`). If you're not, you can remove the old versions and try to restart the browser to see if it loads the correct version.  For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit too and have no issues with libflashplayer loading and running. The version as of 2013-03-17 is 11.2.202.275

Answer (score 0):

Flash installing is not hard for FireFoxes, but you have to reconcile with yourself to deal with kind of devil regarding the fact that even OpenSource-Gnash developers are not allowed to use adobe flash by law..

1]Get the **tar.gz** from official Adobe(R) Flash(R) site by pressing the "Download" button
from https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html

2]
Extract that tar.gz's **libflashplayer.so**, the other files can be ignored and deleted

3] Open a file manager like nautilus or whatever and paste the **libflashplayer.so** into (If there is no directory called "plugins" in your hidden .mozilla folder then just create it with *right-klick-New and name it "**plugins**") in your home-directory

CLI alternative (not as root):

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
mv /path/where/you/extracted/libflashplayer.so ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

4] (Close and) Open Firefox and check in address bar if Shockwave Player is there

```
about:plugins
```

(If you followed instructions it is there! Just disable other flash stuff in "Extras → Add-ons" to be sure the proprietary one is used)

Have fun with it as long as HTML5 won't chase it out of earth;)