# "a Plugin is Required" but I have already installed it from Software Center

Tags: firefox, plugins

Every time I play games, I see that a plugin is required, but I have already installed "flash" from software center. And also, I am able to see youtube videos but still this is only happening in firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must restart Firefox to load installed plugins. The same for Chrome/ium. Plugins are loaded at startup time.

Comment: restarted but still and also rebooted. what to do now?

Comment: You sure is a flash video and no other thing?

Comment: yes, and please try to speak english properly. i cant understand you. I can see videos but not able to play games

Comment: Checking the image, you need a Shockwave player. But this is not available in Ubuntu (Linux). Check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/48140/169736